# How to solve the error "The localhost page isn’t working" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a web application in `Laravel 5`. I created the project in a local machine at my workplace and it runs just fine. But when i run the machine in another windows machine, it gives me an error `The localhost page isn’t working` with `HTTP ERROR 500 as a server internal error`.

I have also tried to look at the `laravel.log` file and found an exception `Call to undefined function site_url()` but don't know how to fix this.

Any idea on how to work around this is much appreciated.

Comment: check server log file.

Comment: I am not sure of my answer, but do you have load your helper ? `$this->load->helper('url');`

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming because you forgot to start laravel service.

If you wish to run your project on http://localhost:8000 Try with the following command :

```
php arisan serve
```

If you wish to choose specific port then try with the following command :

```
php artisan serve --port={port number}
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run local server by `php artisan serve` it will give url `localhost:8000` by default and will run only in your machine to run in another machine of LAN you need to first find Local IP by `ipconfig` suppose you get this (`192.168.2.10`) then use this command.

```
   `php artisan serve --host 192.168.2.10`
```

this will give url `192.168.2.10:8000` and can be access from any LAN connected machine.

Comment: I create the project in one of my local machines in xampp stack,and when i run it in another local machine in xampp,it gives me that error

Comment: Ok try to generate another key `php artisan key:generate`  and clear view and cache. `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I just tried your work around,the error is still there

Answer (score 1):

In case none of this was working for you, there may be a more sinister explanation.

In our case, someone who shall go unnamed accidentally deleted the public/index.php file, and committed that to git! So taboo I didn't even think to look. This will stop ANYTHING in your site from running, including logging, but the server will go ahead, so there is nothing to go on, just a 500 error with no response or preview.

Again, seems ridiculous, but it was SO ridiculous who would even look for it?

Comment: Although this is more a comment it might be indeed a possibility for OP to explore. In this case OP should reply here let let others know if it worked or not because this cannot be tested by others than OP self.

Answer (score 0):

please change your php version. you need to install php 7.2 version for laravel 5.6 version.